# Fetch API in sync functions and for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

```
var lineArr = [];
    var MAX_LENGTH = 10;
    var duration = 500;
    var chart = realTimeLineChart();

function getData() {
  fetch('./getRealTimeData').then((response) => response.json()
.then((data) => {
  return data;
}));
}

function seedData() {
  var now = new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; ++i) {
    let data = getData();
    lineArr.push({
      time: new Date(now.getTime() - ((MAX_LENGTH - i) * duration)),
      x: data.x,
      y: data.y,
      z: data.z
    });
  }
}

function updateData() {
  var now = new Date();
  let data = getData();

  var lineData = {
    time: now,
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y,
    z: data.z
  };
  lineArr.push(lineData);

  if (lineArr.length > 30) {
    lineArr.shift();
  }
  d3.select("#chart").datum(lineArr).call(chart);
}

function resize() {
  if (d3.select("#chart svg").empty()) {
    return;
  }
  chart.width(+d3.select("#chart").style("width").replace(/(px)/g, ""));
  d3.select("#chart").call(chart);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  seedData();
  window.setInterval(updateData, 250);
  d3.select("#chart").datum(lineArr).call(chart);
  d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
});
```

result:

```
rt_st.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at seedData (rt_st.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (rt_st.js:53)
```

Because fetch is async it can have many problems to use in sync context, an don't understand how I can make this getData() function waiting while a request to the server is executed? Or what can I use instead fetch? Or I should use something else than fetch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[async function - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> An async function can contain an await expression
>   that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the
>   passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's
>   execution and returns the resolved value.

---

Add the `async` keyword to all functions that use `getData()` and use the `await` keyword when you call `getData()`:

```
async function seedData() {
  // ...
  let data = await getData();
  // ...

function updateData() {
  var now = new Date();
  let data = await getData();
  // ...
```